# How to use Google Street View Publish API to publish in video mode?

Tags: api, publish, mode, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

We are trying to develop a utility to upload GSV tours that consist of a series of 12K and 14K 360 photos shot along each route. The GPS data is recorded with a GPS logger. For efficiency, we would like to convert each tour/series into a video and upload it using the Google Street View Publish API. We've found where it explains the metadata track (camm) required for the video. However, We have searched the API documentation and cannot seem to find where it explains how to upload the actual videos. Can anyone help? Thank you.